# Writing data from c++ application to a database

Tags: c++, database

I have an application in C++ which needs to record a large amount of data in a database. In general, this task is straight-forward whereby I can use any database-connector in c++ and get the job done.

However, I intend to separate the task from other critical path or basically, separate this utility from the main application. Can you suggest an efficient way? Or writing to the DB is itself efficient/safe enough?

I am thinking of writing the data to some file and running a separate script in the back-ground to dump the data appended to the file in the database. Is this a reasonable approach? Or is writing to a file equally inefficient/unsafe as writing to a database?

Thanks

Comment: what are your concerns with doing the inserts directly?  With the file approach, you will have 'yet another' version of the data to manage. (one in the app, one in the transfer file, and one in the db) - I would think you want to minimize this.

Comment: Database? Which database? SQL?

Comment: @Randy My concerns with direct insert are two fold. One, I want to remove not so critical process from the main one and the other is speed. By using separate thread for database writing, I can get around with first problem but I can but don't want to do that if there exist a better way.

Comment: Isn't SQL a query language, rather than a database?

Comment: @Johnsyweb They probably meant "Microsoft SQL Server". If you think they should have said so explicitly, I agree ;)

Comment: How soon after the data is collected does it have to be *read* (from the database)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you need to ask yourself is:

*Do I need **durability**?*

Durability is the aspect of ACID transactions and it essentially means that when DBMS signals to the client that the transaction has committed, the changes made by that transactions are guaranteed to be persistent. So even if there is a power outage immediatelly after commit, the data is safe.

- If the answer is "no", then you are free to spin-off a background thread that will write to the database, possibly long after the "main" processing has finished.
- If the answer to that question is "yes", then you have no choice but to do your insert "in place", or at the very least make sure the background thread has finished before you finish the "main" processing.

In any case, properly binding parameters and preparing your INSERT statements should help the performance.

If you go the background thread route, you'd probably want to pass the data as it becomes available via a message queue, so the writing to the database can happen in parallel with your "main" processing.

Comment: I am a little hesitant to adopt the background thread approach. I was thinking of dumping the data to some kind of quick read/write repository and then use it from there to supply other consumers of data and I want to do this as a part of a separate application. Now, I understand very little about these things but say if I were to write data to database, file or any other medium all at the same time then running everything on a background thread with compromise the latency of actual application. I may be very well wrong in my understanding. 
I need to read more about message queues and stuff.

Comment: If your goal is to minimize the latency of the "main" processing, then the background thread is exactly the approach I'd recommend. Things would works essentially as follows: (1) Main thread starts producing rows. (2) As soon as a new row is produced, it is put to the message queue. (3) At that point, the main thread is free to **immediately** continue processing. (4) The background thread consumes the rows from the queue and writes them to database **in parallel** to main thread. (5) Main thread produces all the rows it was meant to produce and finishes, without ever waiting for the database.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions:

(1. Use a separate lower priority thread for data writing

(2. Use a separate process: Spawn a "worker" or "data-writer" process and feed it data through a pipe or another IPC mechanism. You can pipe the data via a separate lower priority thread.
Although this is more work than spawning a thread the benefits are that you can easily spawn many worker processes for scaling in the future if need be. If your worker crashes, the critical path remains unhurt.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I've been 'making a live' for long time, updating and inserting large datasets in Sql Server, and I absolutely suggest to follow the route you are thinking of.

For insert, bulkcopy in the target table.

For updates, bulkcopy ìn a temporary table, then issue a 'update in join' (see the docs for the syntax, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/sql-server-update-from-select) related post on SO).

You will need to verify that the recovery mode of your db it's appropriate, to avoid unwanted growth of transaction log. Details vary with SqlServer version...

When I used it (dblibrary in c), bulkcopy had several shortcomings. If you can code in managed C++, I suggest to look at provided class [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx).